# Xception model input_shape size

Tags: cnn

When I set Xception input_shape=None, use the (299,299) dataset for training, and use the (149,149) image when doing the test. Will the (149,149) image be upsampled when it is input to the network?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the Xception Model implemented in Keras, have a look at the documentation:

https://keras.io/api/applications/xception/

> **Arguments**   [...]
>
> - **input_shape**: optional shape tuple, only to be specified if `include_top` is False (otherwise the input shape has to be `(299, 299, 3)`. It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 71. E.g. `(150, 150, 3)` would be one valid value.

You either need to specify an exact input size or use the default value if you don't specify one. If you use images of different sizes, you have to choose a size and upscale / downscale the images to all have the same size.